# Is it safe to drive a car without fixing battery in place

Tags: battery, stuck-bolt

I was trying to change my battery but I overturned and broke the bolt that connects the rod to the frame which fixes the battery in place. Now I need someone to remove that broken bolt and give me a new bolt so that I can attach the rod.

I'm wondering if I can drive the car to a mechanic who will remove the broken bolt. Or can the battery move too much while driving and can this be dangerous? That is, should I call someone near the car instead?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty safe. The main issue in some vehicles is that the battery can slide into an accessary pulley and grind a hole in the battery. Your AC and coolant lines are blocking that from happening. I'd recommend using a bungee cord to strap it down, and forgetting about it. (Throughout history, a bungee cord has been a popular and fairly effective tool for securing batteries.)

Comment: That's an answer @the_storyteller.

Comment: @the_storyteller You mean I can just use a bungee cord and not even bother with getting the broken bolt removed and fixing the rod on top of the battery?

Comment: GdD, I agree, it's an answer and to the_storyteller, transpose your comment to the answer field. Add in a suggestion to check the bungee cord periodically for damage and wear, and you'll get my vote.

Comment: Fix the broken bolt and put original bracket in place is best solution, anything else is temporary until you do a proper fix.

Comment: Seen batteries bounce against bungees and short on the hood - even explode... just do it properly.

Comment: Don't forget that if you have to emergency brake, that battery is not going to stay where it is. It could dent the bonnet (hood) from the inside.

Comment: On an older pickup, I once had a battery tip over and push the spinning fan blade into the radiator fins. Not a pretty sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks pretty safe.

The main issue in some vehicles is that the battery can slide into an accessary pulley and grind a hole in the battery. Your AC and coolant lines are blocking that from happening.

I'd recommend using a bungee cord to strap it down.

Ideally you should fix the bracket, but a bungee cord, when properly applied, works great. They have been an effective tool throughout history for securing batteries.